# I tried making a stop watch using datetime and the Clock.schedule_interval method to print the count down but for some reason it isn't working

Tags: python, kivy

I tried making a stop watch using datetime and the Clock.schedule_interval method to print the count down but for some reason it isn't working

```
#the aim of this code is to make the computer print the reading on the stopwatch will the clock is    
#scheduling
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app  import App
import datetime


class Bellaciao():
    tl  = datetime.datetime(2020,4,14,0,0,0)
    d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)

    #this is the method that performs the logic
    def tik(self):
        self.tl+=self.d
        print(self.tl.time())

class MsApp(App):
    c=Bellaciao()
    def build(self):
        self.c = Bellaciao()

        *#This is where I called the method*
        Clock.schedule_interval( self.c.tik(),1)
        return self.c.tik()

MsApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Clock.schedule_interval( self.c.tik(),1)
```

You're *calling* `self.c.tik()` and scheduling the result...which is None.

Instead do `Clock.schedule_interval(self.c.tik, 1)`.